# Merge freerdp and xfreerdp

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we merge [freerdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freerdp) and [xfreerdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xfreerdp), please?  Most if not all the [freerdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freerdp) questions are about [xfreerdp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xfreerdp).